# How does Telegram web hide its API requests from the browser network tab?

Tags: javascript, http, websocket, browser, telegram

I noticed Telegram Web (k) somehow manages to hide its API (MTProto) calls. I looked at their [repository](https://github.com/morethanwords/tweb/tree/master/src/lib/mtproto/transports) to figure out what kind of requests are used in the browser but I think it's not anything different than websockets (I'm not sure though)

I checked every mode of network inspector (All, HTTP, ws, etc.) but nothing shows any call made.

[image: Telegram web hides API calls from browser inspect]

Answer (score 1):

Telegram uses the web socket and transfers all data packets with the socket

All data transmitted on the socket is encrypted with the MTProto protocol and you cannot read any data in the packets.

For more information, you can take a look at [this address](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto)

Note: Telegram k version can use http connection as fall back connection instead of socket connection, but still use MTProto protocol